# How to define new Model in ATK4

Tags: php, atk4

From: http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/understand/model/add

```
class Model_MyModel extends Model_Table {

    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->addField('name');
    }
}
```

From: http://agiletoolkit.org/intro/models

```
class Model_MyModel extends Model_Table {

    function defineFields(){
        parent::defineFields();
        $this->addField('name');
    }
}
```

Which is correct? What's the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Agile Data has been refactored into a separate framework:
>   http://git.io/ad
>
> The up-to-date way for defining the model is documented here:
>   http://agile-data.readthedocs.io/en/develop/model.html

---

using the init() method is the right one. defineField is old way and was changed in favor of "init" due to consistency.

I will update the pages accordingly.